# Can't spawn creep with memory

Tags: screeps

*First off, I'm completely new to the game, but i know js since before. The problem I'm having is a result of me playing around in the simulator.*

I'm trying to spawn a creep, I started by modifying the [example in the tutorial](https://github.com/screeps/tutorial-scripts/blob/master/section4/main.js):

```
Game.spawns['HQ'].spawnCreep(
  [WORK,CARRY,MOVE], 
  name,
  {memory: {role: r}});
```

But this just spawns a creep with its memory being `undefined`.

[image]

I've also tried setting the memory after calling `spawnCreep`:

```
Game.creeps[name].memory = {
    role: r
};
```

But it results in the same "error".

What am I missing?

**Update1:**

It gets worse... I decided to throw out my entire code base, and replace it with the exact code from the tutorial. And the memory is STILL `undefined`...

```js
var roleHarvester = require('role.harvester');
var roleUpgrader = require('role.upgrader');

module.exports.loop = function () {

    for(var name in Memory.creeps) {
        if(!Game.creeps[name]) {
            delete Memory.creeps[name];
            console.log('Clearing non-existing creep memory:', name);
        }
    }

    var harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'harvester');
    console.log('Harvesters: ' + harvesters.length);

    if(harvesters.length < 2) {
        var newName = 'Harvester' + Game.time;
        if(Game.spawns['HQ'].spawnCreep([WORK,CARRY,MOVE], newName,
            {memory: {role: 'harvester'}}) === OK) {
            console.log('Spawning new harvester: ' + newName);
        };
    }

    if(Game.spawns['HQ'].spawning) {
        var spawningCreep = Game.creeps[Game.spawns['HQ'].spawning.name];
        Game.spawns['HQ'].room.visual.text(
            '️' + spawningCreep.memory.role,
            Game.spawns['HQ'].pos.x + 1,
            Game.spawns['HQ'].pos.y,
            {align: 'left', opacity: 0.8});
    }

    for(var name in Game.creeps) {
        var creep = Game.creeps[name];
        if(creep.memory.role == 'harvester') {
            roleHarvester.run(creep);
        }
        if(creep.memory.role == 'upgrader') {
            roleUpgrader.run(creep);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update2:** 
I decided to try the same code on a private server (aka, not in the simulation as I did before), and now the code works as it should. This leaves only one conclusion, the simulation is bugged.

Comment: I ran your code in the sim, putting in values for `name` and `r` and could not reproduce the problem. The memory was set correctly.

Comment: Curious to know how you got on. I'm having the same issue, was working on a friends private server, now isn't; does work just fine on my own localhost server, same code...

Comment: @Aaron Never got it to work as i wanted, so i stopped playing the game years ago.

Comment: @Olian04 thank you. I found the cause and have provided a full answer in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a " ' " around the r to define it as an string. As far as I can see r is `undefined`.

```js
Game.spawns['HQ'].spawnCreep([WORK,CARRY,MOVE], 
                             name,
                             {memory: {role: 'r'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, was working on a friends private server, then wasn't; worked fine on my own server.

Checking out the memory I noticed my new room wasn't listed in the array of rooms and this lead me to the cause.

Long story short in one of the old rooms I'd had a runaway queue which consumed all 2048KB of memory. Meaning any new memory operations failed.

I ran each of the following in the console then respawned, it's working fine now...

```
Memory.creeps = {};
Memory.spawns = {};
Memory.rooms = {};
Memory.flags = {};
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried ensuring that `Memory.creeps` exists? You can create the key by running the below code in the console on the server you are having this issue on:

```
if (!Memory.creeps) Memory.creeps = {};
```

This often turns out to be the solution whenever I have this issue—though why `Memory.creeps` sometimes turns out to be `undefined` in certain conditions, I don't know.